# How to send a proper message to Console application using user32.dll's SendMessage

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send text to the console when it requires Console.Readline() input, from a different thread (Windows form with a textbox). The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to send text and have it show up exactly as I wrote it.

Example: "test TEST 123" will show up in the console as: test test &é"
Image: http://puu.sh/gIjW8/e9f4d94bd5.png

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("User32.Dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA")]
        private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern short VkKeyScan(char ch);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        internal static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        public static IntPtr hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                TextBox tb = (sender as TextBox);

                /*for (int i = 0; i < tb.Text.Length; i++)
                {
                PostMessage(hWnd, 0x100, (IntPtr)VkKeyScan(tb.Text[i]), 0); -> This crap doesn't support UPPERCASE and numbers <.<
                }*/

                PostMessage(hWnd, 0x100, (IntPtr)Keys.Enter, 0);
                tb.Clear();
            }
            SendMessage(hWnd, 0x000C, 0, "HerpityDerp"); // -> This crap only changes the console title -_-
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using SendMessage, but it only changes the Console's title :/

I'd be very thankful if you guys could come up with a solution

Answer (score 0):

A console app usually doesnt have a windows message pump, you might want to see how you can hook the console's stdout...